# Animating tableviewcell after I deactivate a constraint of its subview

Tags: swift, autolayout, tableview, constraints, cell

I have a cell that has a textview with fixed size of n. When I press a button I deactivate that height constraint, and the cell resizes due to tableview being setup for dynamic cell sizes. The only thing that bothers me that I can't seem to make it animate the change in size. It rather "binary", contracted or expanded. I've tried reload rows at indexpath, beginupdates-endupdates, but I've hit a wall. I'd appreciate any suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you want to animate constraint changes you can generally do it with the constraint change followed by a 
`UIView.animate(withDuration:1){self.view.layoutIfNeeded() }`

if you try to animate the actual constraint change it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can place `layoutIfNeeded()` in a regular `animate(withDuration...)` method but creating a Core Animation transaction allows you to use a custom timing (easing) curve.

```
CATransaction.begin()
someViewConstraintDefault.isActive = false
someViewConstraintNew.isActive = true
CATransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.25, 1, 0.25, 1))
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: { [weak self] in

    self?.view.layoutIfNeeded()

})
CATransaction.commit()
```

This is a great tool for constructing custom timing curves: http://netcetera.org/camtf-playground.html